# Dovecot - Log All IMAP Commands

Tags: linux, logging, dovecot

I have Dovecot 2.2.27 running successfully on Debian Stretch. I have some suspicious activity on my server and I want to log ALL raw IMAP communications sent/received by my server. Here is a .conf file in /etc/dovecot/conf.d/

```
service imap-login {
  executable = imap-login -R rawlogs
}
```

(Source: https://wiki.dovecot.org/Debugging/Rawlog )

Rawlog is recording when a user logs into my IMAP server (Pre-login rawlog). But that's when it stops. It doesn't record any communication after that. I want all IMAP communication received/sent for a connection (logging in, checking mailbox, downloading new mail, etc.)

Here's an example .in file:

```
1523905191.015557 1 LOGIN ***EMAIL ADDRESS HERE*** ***PASSWORD HERE***
```

And the .out file:

```
1523905190.806295 * OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=LOGIN] Dovecot ready.
```

I added the following code to the afore-mentioned .conf file for post-login logging:

```
service imap {
  # tell imap to do post-login lookup using a socket called "imap-postlogin"
  executable = imap imap-postlogin
}

# The service name below doesn't actually matter.
service imap-postlogin {
  # all post-login scripts are executed via script-login binary
  executable = script-login /usr/lib/dovecot/rawlog

  # the script process runs as the user specified here (v2.0.14+):
#  user = $default_internal_user
  user = pksml
  # this UNIX socket listener must use the same name as given to imap executable
  unix_listener imap-postlogin {
  }
}
```

(Source: https://wiki.dovecot.org/PostLoginScripting )

It made no difference. Logging still only exists for authentication and nothing further, even when I'm checking the mail account. Am I doing something wrong, or is this not a capability of Dovecot? Thanks.

PS I have reloaded the Dovecot service after making .conf file changes.

PS #2: Mail users are virtual users, not real Linux system users

---

EDIT - Current `.conf` file:

```
import_environment = $import_environment DEBUG=1

service imap-login {
  executable = imap-login -R rawlogs
}

protocol imap {
  rawlog_dir = /var/run/dovecot/login/rawlogs
}

service imap {
  executable = imap imap-postlogin
}

service imap-postlogin {
  executable = script-login -d /usr/lib/dovecot/rawlog -I
  unix_listener imap-postlogin {
  }
}
```

Comment: I performed that command and the home directory is `/var/mail/vhosts/domain.net/username`. In that directory, I find these directories: `cur, new, tmp` and files: `dovecot.index.log, dovecot-uidlist, dovecot-uidvalidity.5ac2dbd, subscriptions, dovecot.index.cache, dovecot.mailbox.log, dovecot-uidvalidity`. Does that give you the information you're looking for?

Comment: @anx - Appended original post with updated conf file. Still no luck. Only getting pre-login information saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally achieved logging the IMAP commands.

BTW, I set up my server initially using the tutorial at https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mysql/

Here are the relevant dovecot config commands for rawlog:

```
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
userdb {
  args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
  driver = static
}
service imap-login {
  executable = imap-login -R rawlogs
  inet_listener imaps {
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
  }
}
service imap-postlogin {
  executable = script-login -d rawlog
}
service imap {
  executable = imap imap-postlogin
}
protocol imap {
  rawlog_dir = /var/run/dovecot/login/rawlogs
}
```

You get `.in` and `.out` files for authentication stored in `/var/run/dovecot/login/rawlogs` (`rawlog_dir`).

Currently the `rawlog_dir` directory has `777` permissions.

After authentication occurs, the IMAP communication transmitted to/from the server for a particular user is located in the user's home folder in a subfolder named `dovecot.rawlog` (that you must create). For example in my setup, I created the folder `/var/mail/vhosts/domain.com/user/dovecot.rawlog`. This folder has `777` permissions and is owned by `root:vmail`.

Note: In these `.in` and `.out` files you will see all IMAP information transmitted, ***including emails*** in plain text. Also note that this folder will ***quickly*** fill up with files. Keep an eye on it.

Concluding thoughts: The most likely use for raw logging is for debugging or understanding the IMAP protocol. 
It's not a good idea to leave it turned on for months on end!

Answer (score 0):

> **doveadm log errors**

Or and old solution for live logging filtering:

> **tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep dovecot**